# Significance of ';' after for loop condition in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, special-characters

```
const arr = []
for(let i=0 ; i<=5 ; i++ );{
  arr.push(i)
 }
console.log(arr)
```

Can anyone explain me this scenario ?

Comment: Have you tried running the code to see what happens? That will give you a hint as to what the `;` is doing...

Comment: The common name for that is "typo".  It is a mistake -- a bug.  It renders the `for` loop useless.  It is a very tricky bug to find.

Comment: please change 'let' type to 'var'. then it won't give you error. But I'm not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I just rewrite above code.
In for loop i will be increase from 0 to 5, when i reaches to 6, it will be return through i<=5.
and push 6 to arr. that's it.

```js
const arr = []
for(var i=0 ; i<=5 ; i++){} // i will be from 0 to 6.
{ 
  arr.push(i)
}
console.log(arr) // [6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon between round bracket and curly stops the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- If you are trying to push the numbers 0 to 5 into the array, then remove the semicolon (;), else it will cause reference error since i is a let variable.
- If you  want to push only the last value of i (which is 6) then please use var instead of let inside for loop.